# How to rename column encrypted_password in ROR devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to use devise in my ROR project. I have a users table which I can use with devise. I have a column `password` in the users table but device used the column name `encrypted_password` for saving the encrypted password. I tried to rename column name from `encrypted_password` to `password` but nothing was found.

Is there any way to change the column name in a devise module?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a migration to rename a column.

```
class RenamePasswordToEncryptedPassword < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change    
    rename_column :users, :password, :encrypted_password 
  end
end
```

and then run `rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 0):

Renaming column will not seem to work as devise itself defines an attribute named `password`. You should instead rename your existing field to `encrypted_password`.

What you want to do can not be done without breaking core devise functionality. Devise relies on this field and this name is hard-coded. It is not configurable.